# App Drawer with alphabetical order for Ubuntu

Tags: personalization

I don't like GNOME default app launcher as it has no alphabetical order. How will I launch my apps with an App Drawer like Android? Is there any extension available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the alphabetical order GNOME extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4269/alphabetical-app-grid/

[image]
(Image source: [GitHub](https://github.com/stuarthayhurst/alphabetical-grid-extension))